# Opengl Render texture on texture leaves the transparent part as black (see pic)

Tags: opengl-es

The black part of the texture on the top is transparent but renders as black in opengl es .
Im rendering without any blending, dont know is that what I need

How could I solve this issue? Thanks

Here is my shader:

```
    precision mediump float;                           
    varying vec2 v_texCoord;                            
    uniform sampler2D s_texture;
    uniform lowp float distance;
    uniform lowp float slope;     

    void main() 
    {
        highp vec4 color = vec4(1.0);

        highp float d = v_texCoord.y * slope + distance;

        highp vec4 c = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord);

        c = (c - d * color) / (1.0 -d);

        //vec4 textureColor =  texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );


        //gl_FragColor =  textureColor;
        gl_FragColor =  c;
    }
```

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Im rendering without any blending, dont know is taht is waht I need

Yes, if you want something to be transparent, you need either [blending](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending) or to discard fragments based on the alpha value.

Comment: Solved it adding: GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);